# Applying tf.math.argmax on list of tensors

Tags: python, list, tensorflow

tf.math.argmax returns index of maximum value in a tensor.

```
a = tf.constant([1,2,3])
print(a)
print(tf.math.argmax(input = a))
```

output:

```
tf.Tensor([1 2 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=2>
```

I want to apply tf.math.argmax function on a list of tensors. How can I do it.

```
input = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5,6])
split_sequence = tf.split(input, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=-1)
print(split_sequence)
tf.math.argmax(input = split_sequence)
```

output:

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([4, 5, 6], dtype=int32)>]
tf.Tensor([1 2 3 4 5 6], shape=(6,), dtype=int32)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([1, 1, 1])>
```

It is giving wrong indices -> `numpy=array([1, 1, 1]`

desired output:

```
numpy=array([[2],[2]]
```

Comment: How do you store the list of tensors? please add a sample of input and desired output...

Comment: @
I'mahdi
 I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to apply any function on each value in the `list`.

*(It's better don't use [`built-in function`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) of python as a variable so I change `input` to `inp`)*

```
import tensorflow as tf

inp = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5,6])
split_sequence = tf.split(inp, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=-1)
print(split_sequence)

result = list(map(lambda x: [tf.math.argmax(x).numpy()] , split_sequence))
print(result)
```

Or by thanks [@jkr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5666087/jkr), we can use [`List Comprehensions`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0202/) too. [(Which one is better, `map` vs `List comprehension`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6407222/1740577)

```
>>> [[tf.math.argmax(item).numpy()] for item in split_sequence]
[[2], [2]]
```

---

```
[
    <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)>, 
    <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([4, 5, 6], dtype=int32)>
]

[[2], [2]]
```

Benchmark (on [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)):

```
import tensorflow as tf
input = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5,6]*1_000_000)
split_sequence = tf.split(input, num_or_size_splits=20, axis=-1)

%timeit tf.math.top_k(split_sequence, k=1).indices
# 13.5 ms ± 394 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


%timeit list(map(lambda x: [tf.math.argmax(x).numpy()] , split_sequence))
# 14 ms ± 2.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


%timeit [[tf.math.argmax(item).numpy()] for item in split_sequence]
# 8.77 ms ± 113 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: if using map, why not a list comprehension? `[tf.math.argmax(item) for item in split_sequence]`

Comment: @jkr, We can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6407222/1740577), in some cases `map` is better that list comprehension, but here we need to check.

Comment: @jkr, Here `list_comprehension ` is the fastest approach.

Comment: i wasn't thinking about speed. i was thinking about readability. in my humble opinion, the list comprehension is easier to read and it is easier to understand what is happening.

Comment: @jkr, Yes, I agree with you, `list_comprehension` is more readable than using `map` and in this case, is faster too.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend simply using `tf.math.top_k` in your case:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5,6])
split_sequence = tf.split(input, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=-1)
x = tf.math.top_k(split_sequence, sorted=False, k=1).indices
print(x)
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[2]
 [2]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=int32)
```

Afterwards, if you want a `Numpy` array, just call `x.numpy()`.

**Update 1**:
A even simpler but slower approach is to just change the axis of `tf.argmax`:

```
input = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5,6])
split_sequence = tf.split(input, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=-1)
tf.argmax(split_sequence, axis=-1)
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([2, 2])>
```

You do not need any explicit `loop` or `map`. See benchmarks:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5,6]*1_000_000)
split_sequence = tf.split(input, num_or_size_splits=20, axis=-1)

@tf.function
def top_k(split_sequence):
  return tf.math.top_k(split_sequence, k=1, sorted=False).indices

@tf.function
def argmax(split_sequence):
  return tf.argmax(split_sequence, axis=-1)

@tf.function
def _map(split_sequence):
  return list(map(lambda x: [tf.math.argmax(x)] , split_sequence))

@tf.function
def _list(split_sequence):
  return [[tf.math.argmax(item)] for item in split_sequence]

%timeit top_k(split_sequence)
# 3.5 ms ± 246 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit argmax(split_sequence)
# 16.6 ms ± 3.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit _map(split_sequence)
# 10.3 ms ± 929 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit _list(split_sequence)
# 10.2 ms ± 2.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: @AloneTogether Thanks. Doesn't  the top_k method use loop internally? Actually It would be helpful if i avoid using loops because i want to use this code in custom layers in tensorflow.

Comment: Yes, but actually you can just use `tf.argmax` directly as shown in my answer.

Comment: @AloneTogether dose the tf.argmax use grap code for fast execution?

Comment: @ABMusicBox if graph mode execution is activated, see benchbarks. `tf.math.top_k` is fastest in `Graph` mode.

Comment: I have posted a question in which i am trying to build  a coustom layer in ternsorflow where i need to use this code. I would be thankful of you can you 
 help me solve this problem link:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/73527851/13096521. I have gave the  whole code in the question  but need a little help as i dont know a lot about tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, **numpy=2**>

You can see the output in numpy = 2 i.e, 2nd index of your constant which is value 3